# Libsvm : Wrong input format at line 1

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I am trying to use [Libsvm](https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm) and I got the following behaviour:

```
root@bcfd88c873fa:/home/libsvm# ./svm-train myfile
Wrong input format at line 1
root@bcfd88c873fa:/home/libsvm# head -n 5 myfile
2   0:0.00000 8:0.00193 2:0.00000 1:0.00000 10:0.00722
3   6:0.00235 2:0.00000 0:0.00000 1:0.00000 5:0.00155
4   0:0.00000 1:0.00000 2:0.00000 4:0.00187
3   6:0.00121 8:0.00211 1:0.00000 2:0.00000 0:0.00000
3   0:0.00000 2:0.00000 1:0.00000
```

Can you see anything wrong on the format ? It works with other svm implementation such as [this one](https://github.com/xlvector/hector) in Go.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The provided format is correct. The `Java` interface of `LIBSVM 3.22` does process the provided file as expected.

However, I also tried the Windows and Linux interfaces, which behave as described in your question.

```
svm-train.exe myfile
Wrong input format at line 1
```

After investigation, I found that the **feature-ids** have to be **sorted** to be properly processed by the tool (which seems to be a bug as the `Java` interface does not suffer from this restriction...):

```
2   0:0.00000 1:0.00000 2:0.00000 8:0.00193 10:0.00722
3   0:0.00000 1:0.00000 2:0.00000 5:0.00155 6:0.00235
4   0:0.00000 1:0.00000 2:0.00000 4:0.00187
3   0:0.00000 1:0.00000 2:0.00000 6:0.00121 8:0.00211
3   0:0.00000 1:0.00000 2:0.00000
```

Moreover, as `LIBSVM` uses [sparse-data format](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f301) you can simplify your dataset by skipping the features with a value of zero:

```
2   8:0.00193 10:0.00722
3   5:0.00155 6:0.00235
4   4:0.00187
3   6:0.00121 8:0.00211
3
```

Comment: rzo, by any chance, do you the answer to that one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982245/extract-coefficients-weights-from-libsvm-model-file too ?