# Extract coefficients/weights from libsvm model file

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I am using [libsvm](https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm) for creating a 2-classes classifier. 
I wish to extract the coefficient/weight of each feature used by the model generated by `./svm-train training.training model.model`

The `model.model` file looks like:

```
svm_type c_svc
kernel_type rbf
gamma 8
nr_class 2
total_sv 442
rho 21
label 1 -1
nr_sv 188 254
SV
7080.357768871263 0:0 1:0.00643 2:0.01046 3:0.00963 4:0.02777 5:0.04338 19:0.04468 
528.7111702760092 0:0 1:0.00058 3:0.00086 6:0.01158 7:0.0028 9:0.08991 13:0.0096 
...
391.7649705739246 0:0 1:0.00055 3:0.00082 5:0.04615 7:0.06374 21:0.00374 31:0.00339 33:0.00395 38:0.16343 
...
-564.1329424321915 0:0 1:0.00709 2:0.00384 3:0.00709 5:0.00399 9:0.01457 10:0.01244 11:0.0206 17:0.02124 20:0.00565 23:0.00846 27:0.04692 33:0.04271 35:0.02389 36:0.00859 39:0.02014
```

How do I know which coefficients/weights will be used by `svm-predict [options] test.test model.model out.out` ? The ones from the last line ?

Thanks,
M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model file generated by `LIBSVM` consists, according to the offical [FAQ entry](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f402), of the following information:

> In the model file, after parameters and other informations such as
>   labels , each line represents a support vector.
>   Support vectors are listed in the order of "labels" shown earlier. (i.e., those from the
>   first class in the "labels" list are grouped first, and so on.) If k
>   is the total number of classes, in front of a support vector in class
>   j, there are k-1 coefficients y*alpha where alpha are dual solution of
>   the following two class problems:  1 vs j, 2 vs j, ..., j-1 vs j, j vs
>    j+1, j vs j+2, ..., j vs k  and y=1 in first j-1 coefficients, y=-1 in
>   the remaining k-j coefficients. For example, if there are 4 classes,
>   the file looks like:
>
> ```
> +-+-+-+--------------------+
> |1|1|1|                    |
> |v|v|v|  SVs from class 1  |
> |2|3|4|                    |
> +-+-+-+--------------------+
> |1|2|2|                    |
> |v|v|v|  SVs from class 2  |
> |2|3|4|                    |
> +-+-+-+--------------------+
> |1|2|3|                    |
> |v|v|v|  SVs from class 3  |
> |3|3|4|                    |
> +-+-+-+--------------------+
> |1|2|3|                    |
> |v|v|v|  SVs from class 4  |
> |4|4|4|                    |
> +-+-+-+--------------------+
> ```

There is also an [example](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f804) of how to read this data in order to compute `w` for a binary classifier.